# sql - CASE return "true" if you compare NULL to NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-null

`DECODE` will return "true" if you compare `NULL` to `NULL`. `CASE` will not.

How do i make `CASE` to return true if I compare `NULL` to `NULL`?

An example of my current query. One problem is that if `a.name` is `null` and `b.name` is `null`, then it will return false. I want it to behaves like `DECODE` function from oracle sql.

```
SELECT CASE a.name
    WHEN b.name THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END,
FROM Employee1 a, Employee2 b 
WHERE a.salary = b.salary;
```

Comment: You have tagged MySQL and Oracle. These are two different RDBMSes, which are you asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your expression to the other form of `CASE` and test for both `NULL` values as well:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.name IS NULL AND b.name IS NULL OR a.name = b.name THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END
FROM Employee1 a
JOIN Employee2 b ON a.salary = b.salary;
```

Note I've rewritten the query to use modern `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, the answer i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [NULL-safe equal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) we can use:

```
SELECT a.name <=> b.name
FROM Employee1 a
JOIN Employee2 b ON a.salary = b.salary;
```